# jquery, timer or chaining functions?

Tags: jquery

how best to go about cycling through li's and repeating?

should i use a timer or is there a better way?

for example, i want to display li one at a time. when i hit the end i want to go back to top and start again.

Comment: For everybody reading, it sounds like he wants to implement a form of slideshow using unordered lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I'll have a stab at it.

Timers are useful when performing animations, or if you think there's going to be a lot of iterations (so as to not hog the thread).

If you're just creating a few LI elements and appending them to a UL element, and you don't want them to be shown incrementally (like in an animation), just use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The new jQuery `delay()` could come in handy here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').hide();

    function loopLi(element){
       element.fadeIn('slow').delay(5*1000).fadeOut('slow');
       var newElement;
       if(element.is(':last')){
          newElement = element.parents('ul').find('li:first');
       }else{
          newElement = element.next();
       }

       loopLi(newElement);
    }

    loopLi($('ul li:first'));

});
```

UPDATE:

`.delay()` isn't all that I thought it would be. Seems to work in an asynchronous manner, allowing other functions to be called before the li fades in. Here's a better way, with an interval

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li:first').addClass('current');
    $('li:not(:first)').hide();

    var slideshow = setInterval(function (){
       $('li.current').fadeOut('slow');
       var nextElement;
       if($('li.current').is(':eq('+ $('li').length +')')){
         nextElement = $('li:first');
       }else{
         nextElement = $('li.current').next();
       }

       $('li.current').hide().removeClass('current');
       nextElement.addClass('current').fadeIn('slow');
    }, 10*1000);

});
```

Comment: a littl OT, but this func is going to make my life so much eaiser :-)

Comment: this creates out of memory for me

Comment: hmmm...are you using jQuery 1.4?

Comment: i hadn't gotten a chance to use this function before. after trying it, something interesting. it appears it's not a synchronous delay as i thought it was. the function loops through itself many many times before the end of the first delay. something like a setInterval may be better suited for your needs

Answer (score 0):

If you need more feature you could use jCarousel or another carousel type plugin. Not sure what you need your presentation to look like so this may or may not be more trouble than its worth.